# TDD with Python chapter 1 no output from functional_tests.py

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am following the book TDD with Python. In chapter 1 there is a piece of code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase): 

    def setUp(self): 
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    def tearDown(self): 
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self): 
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)  
        self.fail('Finish the test!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

The file is called functional_tests.py. I have django 1.7 and selenium installed globally on Ubuntu 14.04. I also started fresh project superlists. I run the server before I try the tests. When I run the test with

```
 python3 functional_tests.py
```

Firefox window opens up and loads the default Django startup page and the window stays open even though it should close after the test runs. Also there is no output from the tests at all. I was expecting something like this:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "functional_tests.py", line 18, in
test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
AssertionError: 'To-Do' not found in 'Welcome to Django'

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.747s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed recent version of Selenium? As mentioned in the book, you should have matching version of Firefox and Selenium.